# Number of bound variables does not match number of tokens when using a custom PDO function

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, sql-update

I tried the questions with similar titles, but they are all regular queries that are not in functions.

I am trying to create an update function in a Database class so I don't have to write out the entire process over and over. However, I am getting the error:

```
Invalid parameter number: number of bound variables does not match number of tokens
```

Here is my function.

```
 public function updateRow($query, $params) {
    try {
        $stmt = $this->master_db_data->prepare($query);
        foreach($params as $key => $val) {
            $stmt->bindValue($key+1, $val);
            $stmt->execute();
            return true;
        }
    } catch(PDOException $e) {
        die("Error: " . $e->getMessage());
    }
}
```

And its usage:

```
$query = "UPDATE records SET content=?, ttl=?, prio=?, change_date=? WHERE id=?";
$params = array($SOA_content, $fields['SOA_TTL'], '1', $DATE_TIME, $id);
if($db->updateRow($query, $params)) {
    echo "Success";
}
else {
    echo "Fail";
}
```

Doing it without a function works:

```
$pdo = new PDO("mysql:host={$host};dbname={$dbname};charset=utf8", $username, $password, $options);
$query = "UPDATE records SET content=:content, ttl=:ttl, prio=:prio, change_date=:change_date WHERE id=:id";
$stmt = $pdo->prepare($query);
$stmt->bindValue(":content", $SOA_content);
$stmt->bindValue(":ttl", $fields['SOA_TTL']);
$stmt->bindValue(":prio", 1);
$stmt->bindValue(":change_date", $DATE_TIME);
$stmt->bindValue(":id", $id);
$stmt->execute();
```

Am I wrong with my bindValue in the function? If so, how?

Comment: Is `count($params)` equal to placeholders count?

Comment: Do you mean content, ttl, prio, change_date, and id?

Comment: Ah, I see, you need to bind all parameters before executing... you have execute in your binding loop.

Comment: Lol. I'm blind. You'are just calling execute in loop body.

Comment: You also could just pass the `$params` to the `execute`. You don't need the `bindvalue`/`foreach`.

Comment: @Uueerdo You answered my question. I'll accept if you would like to post as an answer. Thank you. I completely missed that.

Comment: This guy has done an excellent video tutorial on setting up a database class with all the function req. to update, insert, delete etc.  https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qZARqGduS8M . Makes updating etc a simple one line operation

Comment: @IRGeekSauce It always feels a little funny to me to put official answers to borderline typo-level errors, but considering how many comments we got in before noticing, you're probably not the first to make this kind of oversight, and won't be the last.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Always make sure your execute calls happen after all binding has been performed. In this situation, move the execute out of the binding loop.